# Is there a way to read the DBMS_Output from Oracle in the Airflow log?

Tags: database, oracle, airflow

I am using the oracle operator in airflow and we have some existing code in Oracle packages/procedures which use dbms_output for some informational output.  Is there a way to read this buffer from airflow log or somehow otherwise retrieve it?

I can see raised errors fine in the log, but not general information entered in the dbms_output/buffer.

I thought it may be missing DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE but that doesn't seem to help.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: IDK anything about airflow, but dbms_output can be read by a client that has called the package/procedure using dbms_output.get_lines.

Comment: This sounded promising.  Thanks for the tip!  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be changing anything for what I am seeing in the airflow log.  Outside of airflow I can get it to read back the buffer but when I try this in the airflow sql script it doesn't seem to have any affect.  But thinking about this further, I could use this as a wrapper and "move" the log from the buffer to another log/table by using this method and not having to alter the existing scripts.

Comment: If you are using SQL\*Plus, or an IDE that supports SQL\*Plus commands, such as SQL Developer, take a look at the `SPOOL` command. This can be used to redirect server output to a specified location, such as a log file. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SPOOL.html#GUID-61492052-ECCB-45C8-AF94-AB9794C60BEA